# Unmarshaling (JSON) in apache camel

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, marshalling

I am new in apache camel. And I wanna do some simple task using apache camel. I have json data available on this url http://localhost:8080/users/. There are json data from my rest service. But I wanna get this json data and unmarshal it to POJO using apache camel and write some data to txt file. But my app starts and then doesnt't stop.

Here is my JSON data available on http://localhost:8080/users/

```html
[{"id":1,"login":"admin","password":"admin","passwordAgain":null,"email":"admin@admin.com","firstName":"Admin","lastName":"Adminovich","birthday":"2010-10-10","role":{"id":1,"name":"admin"}},
{"id":5,"login":"Snow123","password":"1111","passwordAgain":null,"email":"john@snow.com","firstName":"John","lastName":"Snow","birthday":"2010-10-10","role":{"id":2,"name":"user"}}]
```

spring.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    

    <bean id="MyRouteBuilder" class="MyRouteBuilder" init-method="restart">

    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <routeBuilder ref="MyRouteBuilder"/>

    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

MyRouteBuilder

```html
import Mapping.User;
import Mapping.Users;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletConstants;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonLibrary;
import org.restlet.Response;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.data.Status;



public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private String routePort = null;
    private String routeAnswer = null;

    public void restart() {
        String start = "Route Property Placeholder Example started on port" + " 8080" + "!";
        System.out.println(start);
    }

    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:foo?repeatCount=1").to("http://10.10.34.145:8080/users/").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Users.class ).log("STARTED!")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process (Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Users usersList = exchange.getIn().getBody(Users.class);
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(usersList.usersList);
                        System.out.println(usersList.usersList.size());
                    }
                }).to("file:///home/name/username/Desktop/camel.txt").stop();

    }
}
```

User

```html
package Mapping;

import com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class User {

    public User() {

    }

    private int id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String passwordAgain;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String birthday;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setPasswordAgain(String passwordAgain) {
        this.passwordAgain = passwordAgain;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getPasswordAgain() {
        return passwordAgain;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getFirsteName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    private String role;

}
```

Users

```html
package Mapping;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Users {

    public List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

Main

```html
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.enableHangupSupport();

        MyRouteBuilder rb = new MyRouteBuilder();
        main.addRouteBuilder(rb);
        try {
            main.run(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't stop? Do you get any errors? What happens when you run the route?

Comment: App doesn't stop. And I don't have any runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I converted JsonData to Java object and created a custom CSV file using following dependencies.

- jackson-mapper-asl
- jackson-core-asl

You can create simple text file or CSV whatever it is.
This is my route:

```
    from("couchdb:http://localhost:5984/order")
          .startupOrder(1)
          .process(new JsonToCsvProcessor())
          .to("file:/home/r2/Desktop/ofBizFile?fileExist=append&fileName=orders-${date:now:dd-MM-yyyy}.csv");
```

This is my Processor where I am passing JsonString to ObjectMapper for Pojo:

```
{

public void process(Exchange exchange)throws Exception{
    String jsonString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    exchange.getOut().setBody(convertJsonToCSV(jsonString).toString());
      }

public StringBuilder convertJsonToCSV(String jsonStringArgs){

StringBuilder csvFile = new StringBuilder();
 //Here customize data format using append() 
 .     
 .
 return csvFile;
     }

}
```

If you don't know how to use ObjectMapper this link will help you out.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02X6U81MdJ0&t=1s

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the amounts in json's case: Jackson or Gson

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-gson</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I recommend checking the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/json.html)

you can do the unmarshal direct on the route:

`unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyModel.class)`

or you can create a processor:

```
@Component
public class MyModelUnMarshalProccessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        MyModel model = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyModel.class);
        exchange.getOut().setBody(model);
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("id", body.getId());
    }

}

@Autowired
MyModelUnMarshalProccessor myModelUnMarshalProccessor;

from("{{fromServices}}")
   .log("${body}")
   .process(myModelMarshalProccessor)
```

good luck